# Pandas: How to self-join cross-functionally

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe below for airline flights:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    
    'ORIGIN_x':["LGA","ORD"],
    'DESTINATION_x':["ORD","LGA"],
    'number_of_flights_x':[3576,3580],
    'ORIGIN_y':["ORD","LGA"],
    'DESTINATION_y':["LGA","ORD"],
    'number_of_flights_y':[3580,3576]
    
})
```

I am trying to get below output:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({
    
    'ORIGIN_x':["LGA"],
    'DESTINATION_x':["ORD"],
    'ORIGIN_y':["ORD"],
    'DESTINATION_y':["LGA"],
    'number_of_flights':[7156], #sum of 3576+3580
    
})
```

So two sample rows should match and I should see only one row because ORIGIN_x=DESTINATION_y & ORIGIN_y=DESTINATION_x. And I need to sum the number of flights(i.e. sum of number_of_flights_x column)

PS: Sorry if the title of my question is not clear

I tried to do a self-inner join but it is still multiplying the rows.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you already have all the info in each row of the input DataFrame? Then you don't even need a merge, but rather an aggregation + filter.

Comment: @mozway Yes! After I grouped the data and do some aggregation, I came to a point where I have everything I needed in the input dataframe. I am not sure how to combine the rows based on [ORIGIN_x=DESTINATION_y & ORIGIN_y=DESTINATION_x] this logic and sum the number of flights.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have this format in the first place. It doesn't really make sense to duplicate information this way. I showed an example below of how to come back to non duplicated data, but best is to avoid it in the first place. What was the original dataset and used command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your format with duplicated information, I would drop the `_y` and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
import numpy as np

# only keep _x
tmp = df.filter(like='_x').copy()

# sort ORIGIN/DESTINATION always in the same order
tmp[['ORIGIN_x', 'DESTINATION_x']] = np.sort(tmp[['ORIGIN_x', 'DESTINATION_x']])

# aggregate
out = tmp.groupby(['ORIGIN_x', 'DESTINATION_x'], as_index=False).sum()

print(out)
```

Output:

```
  ORIGIN_x DESTINATION_x  number_of_flights_x
0      LGA           ORD                 7156
```

Then, if needed, you can recreate the `_y` columns by  copying the existing ones (swapping ORIGIN and DESTINATION), but IMO this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your entire dataset.

but if it's a set of 2 rows, you can use the following code:

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
grp = np.arange(len(df)) // 2
out = df.groupby(grp).agg({'ORIGIN_x':'first', 'DESTINATION_x':'first', 'number_of_flights_x':'sum'})
```

out:

```
ORIGIN_x    DESTINATION_x   number_of_flights_x
0   LGA     ORD             7156
```

Since the code only applies to some columns, you need to modify the code to apply it to other columns.

If you want to change the column name, you can use `rename` to change `number_of_flights_x` to `number_of_flights`.

Comment: Panda Kim I have a bunch of similar rows. mozway solution worked! Thank you so much for trying to help.